# How to setup databases on ArcadeDB instance?

Tags: docker, sh, git-bash, graph-databases, arcadedb

I cannot see my databases on ArcadeDB Website.
But I can see them both on the CLI.
What am I missing on setting-up or running-on ArcadeDB?

1. Setup with their [Getting-Started](https://arcadedb.com/) Guide

```bash
docker run --rm -p 2480:2480 -p 2424:2424
           -e JAVA_OPTS="-Darcadedb.server.rootPassword=playwithdata -Darcadedb.server.defaultDatabases=Imported[root]{import:https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb-datasets/raw/main/orientdb/OpenBeer.gz}"
           arcadedata/arcadedb:latest
```

2. Create 2nd `food` DB with their [ArcadeDB-Doc's JSON-Importer](https://docs.arcadedb.com/#JSON-Importer)

```
~/arcadedb $ create database food 
~/arcadedb $ import database https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/fdc-datasets/FoodData_Central_foundation_food_json_2022-10-28.zip
with mapping = {
    "FoundationFoods": [{
        "@cat": "v",
        "@type": "<foodClass>",
        "foodNutrients": [{
            "@cat": "e",
            "@type": "HAS_NUTRIENT",
            "@in": "nutrient",
            "@cardinality": "no-duplicates",
            "nutrient": {
                "@cat": "v",
                "@type": "Nutrient",
                "@id": "id",
                "@idType": "long",
                "@strategy": "merge"
            },
            "foodNutrientDerivation": "@ignore"
        }],
        "inputFoods": [{
            "@cat": "e",
            "@type": "INPUT",
            "@in": "inputFood",
            "@cardinality": "no-duplicates",
            "inputFood": {
                "@cat": "v",
                "@type": "<foodClass>",
                "@id": "fdcId",
                "@idType": "long",
                "@strategy": "merge",
                "foodCategory": {
                    "@cat": "e",
                    "@type": "HAS_CATEGORY",
                    "@cardinality": "no-duplicates",
                    "@in": {
                        "@cat": "v",
                        "@type": "FoodCategory",
                        "@id": "id",
                        "@idType": "long",
                        "@strategy": "merge"
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

From that,
With a slight substitution because its in a Docker-container instead of a local-instance;
To this

```bash
$ docker cp FoodData_Central_foundation_food_json_2022-10-28.zip 
$ winpty docker exec -it arcadeDB_container sh 
# bin/console.sh 
> create database food 
> import database file://home/arcadedb/Downloads/FoodData_Central_foundation_food_json_2022-10-28.zip with mapping = {"FoundationFoods": [{"@cat": "v","@type": "<foodClass>","foodNutrients": [{"@cat": "e","@type": "HAS_NUTRIENT","@in": "nutrient","@cardinality": "no-duplicates","nutrient": {"@cat": "v","@type": "Nutrient","@id": "id","@idType": "long","@strategy": "merge"},"foodNutrientDerivation": "@ignore"}],"inputFoods": [{"@cat": "e","@type": "INPUT","@in": "inputFood","@cardinality": "no-duplicates","inputFood": {"@cat": "v","@type": "<foodClass>","@id": "fdcId","@idType": "long","@strategy": "merge","foodCategory": {"@cat": "e","@type": "HAS_CATEGORY","@cardinality": "no-duplicates","@in": {"@cat": "v","@type": "FoodCategory","@id": "id","@idType": "long","@strategy": "merge"}}}}]}]}
> list databases 

Databases:
- Imported 
- food
```

Both the CLI and the website know about `food` DB:
As seen by the `list databases` on the CLI, and
As seen by the create `food` DB response on the website
`Cannot execute command Database 'food' already exists`.
But I cannot see-or-select on the website dropdown options.

Why can I not use the `food` DB on the website?

I've tried:

1. Restarting and recreating the Docker container
2. Restarting Docker and the host-computer
3. Refreshing, Re-logging-in, and incognito-mode-ing the ArcadeDB website

I was expecting to see the DB show up on the Website selection options.

I see everything but the website allowing me to use the other DB from the dropdown selection.

Comment: https://discord.com/channels/883057780553052180/883057780553052184/1088810608167759897

Comment: https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb/discussions/967#discussion-4996310

Comment: https://github.com/ArcadeData/arcadedb/issues/645#issue-1466408318